# How to implement and use rotation matrix python?

Tags: python, matrix, 3d, rotation

I'm trying to perform complex rotations of a point around the origin in a 3d space. I know my starting point and the target ending point. I'm trying to find the rotation matrix and apply it to the starting point to see if I get the target point. I think my rotation matrix calculation is incorrect but I dont know why. I based it off of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/476311/899558).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

def get_rot_matrix(A, B):
    assert A.shape == B.shape
    v = np.cross(A, B)
    s = np.linalg.norm(v)
    c = np.dot(A, B)
    vx = np.array([[0, -v[2], v[1]], [v[2], 0, -v[0]], [-v[1], v[0], 0]]) 
    r = np.eye(3) + vx + (np.dot(vx, vx) * (1-c)/(s**2))
    return r   

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# ORIGIN
ax.scatter(0,0,0)

point = np.array([3,2,5])

# STARTING
ax.scatter(point[0], point[1], point[2])

# vector magnitude (pythagreon)
length = math.sqrt(sum(a**2 for a in point))

# TARGET POINT
ax.scatter(0, 0, length)

# calc rotation matrix
R = get_rot_matrix(np.array(point), np.array([0, 0, length]))

# RESULT
result_point = np.dot(R, point)
print("Result:")
print(result_point)
ax.scatter(result_point[0], result_point[1], result_point[2])

plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.legend(["origin", "start", "target", "result"])
ax.set_xlim3d(-1,6)
ax.set_ylim3d(-1,6)
ax.set_zlim3d(-1,6)
plt.show()
```

Result point does not appear on the chart:

```
Result:
[-1.06581410e-14 -2.30926389e-14  2.34247732e+02]
```

Comment: Why do you think that your rotation matrix is incorrect?

Comment: @mkrieger1 because the result is not the same as the target. And the R matrix calculations are probably the most prone to error in my code.